# How to multiply two tensors' axes in PyTorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, matrix-multiplication, tensor

I have two 3D tensors of shape:

```
a = torch.full([1495, 110247, 1], 0.5)
b = torch.full([1495, 110247, 2], 1)
```

I want to multiply them so that the first two dimensions remain the same and the third dimension is the scalar product of the third dimension of `a` and `b`.

Comment: What's wrong with `a*b`?